# Example of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

So I need to construct a holomorphic on unit disc function $f=u+iv$ for which $u$ is bounded and $v$ not bounded. So far I can construct two harmonic functions - one bounded and one unbounded but these two functions must also satisfy Cauchy-Riemann conditions it's hard. So how can I do that?

Comment: If you know the Riemann Mapping Theorem that gives a very simple solution

Comment: I know only that for every simply connedcted domain in $\mathbb{C}$  there exist conformal mapping form it to unit disc. And how can I get unboundness from that?

Comment: The inverse $g$ of that is a mapping from the disk to the domain. If the domain is ... then it's clear that $g$ has bounded real part and unbounded imaginary part

Comment: So domain is some sort of cylinder with infinitely tall wrt imaginary part

Comment: $i\log(1-z)$ works